# ScrollView scrolls down when view size changes

Tags: android, scrollview

I currently have a ScrollView with a LinearLayout. I'm changing some content dynamically, e.g. setting a long text passage dynamically, and adding dynamic layouts (buttons etc.). This causes the linear layout's height to change, which causes the ScrollView to scroll down. How can I keep the current scroll position while the layout is being dynamically updated?

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <!-- Dynamic Content Here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try this? or downvote me into oblivion... see if i care.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648526/manage-scroll-position-in-scrollview-during-orientation-change?

Comment: I could try storing the position and then restoring, but that would mean I would have to listen for each individual view's layout which will get pretty messy, especially if we take user touches into consideration. I'll save this if there is no alternative.

Comment: I had the same problem, i fix it with the solution posted by mjp66 http://stackoverflow.com/a/14632456/4712031

Comment: @Leo's link to mjp66's answer worked for me. At the time of writing it is the correct answer and has 220 up-votes including mine.

Answer (score -1):

One option i would suggest is to save the scroll position in a bundle and restore it.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("xPos", scrollView.getScrollX());
    outState.putInt("yPos", scrollView.getScrollY());
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    int scrollX = savedInstanceState.getInt("xPos"); // Default value 0
    int scrollY = savedInstanceState.getInt("yPos");
    scrollView.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think with this steps you can do it :

- Create a custom scroll view that extends from scrollview
- Define a boolean property for enabling and disabling scroll
- Check the boolean variable on the onScollChanged method and return false if is true
- Set the boolean variable true before adding dynamic views to it's container
- Set it to false when adding done

I hope these help you

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work due to the fact that computeScroll is called some time after the view has been added to the layout, which would mean that I would again have to keep track of layout changes...

Comment: You want add the views dynamically after that activity loaded and content view set ? Or you are setting the content view after adding new views to root view ?

Comment: I am loading the activity, fetching some data then adding the data and adding dynamic views into the layout.